# Al conectar a un servicio WCF se queda en "scaffolding service reference code"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, wcf, wsdl

Al conectarme a un servicio WCF con su WSDL en VisualStudio, al momento de realizar la conexión, se queda en el paso:
"scaffolding service reference code"
lleva en este punto una hora y no termina, es esto normal? Se debe a que la dirección del wsdl es incorrecta y no encuentra el servicio? gracias.

Comment: Al parecer es un error de VisualStudio 15 y ya fue corregida en la versión 17. Te recomiendo visitar esta solución en Github: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2994#issuecomment-402354964 . Posibles soluciones: actualizar Visual Studio a su última versión ó, si no quieres actualizar VisualStudio, entonces usar la herremienta dotnet-svcutil.

Comment: Tengo la versión 16, por lo que probablemenet sea eso, muchas gracias!